# Maui blazor how to Trust Self Signed or ingore ssl error

Tags: c#, blazor, ssl-certificate, maui

I want build a cross-platform app for proxmox ve client by muai blazor.

I had clone noVNC in my project wwwroot and want use websockets to connect my vm.

For convenience, users may use IP for access, which will cause certificate exceptions.

I created an iframe containing a websocket url，The program denied access for security reasons
。

```html
url = "/novnc/vnc.html?autoconnect=true&encrypt=true&host=" + Vars.Host + "&port="+ Vars.HostPort +"&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(vm_vnc_password) + "&path=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path); ;
```

```cs
<div id="parent">
    <div id="wrapper" style="position:relative">
        <iframe style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:90%;height:90vh;" src="@url"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Friends, do you have any suggestions?